# Apache Mahout 0.9 - NaiveBayes in Java

Tags: apache, classification, mahout

I am looking for simple example in Java (without any shell call) how to use NaiveBayesClassifier in Apache Mahout 0.9.

I have a samples of text. I want to learn algorithm base on this data and that I want to classify a new text.

There is no example how to do it in Apache Mahout 0.9 !

Answer (score 0):

Look at the test program NaiveBayesTest.java for an example. Please post to Mahout user@ mailing lists for better and quicker responses.